# Any option to open our app in the "Share-List of the Browser"

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, browser, ios6

Is there any way to capture every link tapped on mobile browser? so it will redirect to my ios application.

Or while taping on link will be able to give option of sharing with own created service.

For example- in android browser when you pressed a link you will get an option to share it with existing sharing application like whatsapp etc. Is there any way to create same for ios?

Or creating addons for mobile browser.

Comment: @eptdeveloper i don't think this is a proper way say like that. if you don't know else u have answer then give with proper way do not insulting other. the man who asking that question is quite newbie.

Comment: @NitinGohel : intension is not to hurt your feelings just laughing on imagination i appreciate and love his idea you got me wrong and once at a while it happens that mobile browser also supports Add-ons then on that day we both will laugh :) still sorry if i hurt you buddy.

Comment: that parson is not my buddy i just thout that type of kidding is dump to other who are newbie.